# Assigning value to the location pointed by one pointer affects the value of another pointer

Tags: c, pointers

```
//foo.c

#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int a = 1;
    int *pn = &a;
    printf("%lld\n", (long long int) pn);

    char *pc = ((char *) pn ) + 4 * (sizeof(char));
    printf("%lld\n", (long long int) pn);

    *pc = '\0'; //This assignment changes the value of pn.
    printf("%lld\n", (long long int) pn);
}
```

In the above C program, the character pointer `pc` points to a location next to the integer pointer `pn`. The assignment `*pc = '\0'` changes the value of `pn`.

```
gcc -o foo foo.c
./foo
```

Here is the output:

```
140736942845732
140736942845732
140736942845696
```

Could you see why assignment to `*pc` affects the value of `pn`?

Comment: It is undefined behavior whatever you are trying.

Comment: "the character pointer pc points to a location next to the integer pointer pn". How did you come to that conclusion?

Comment: Use `%p` to print the pointer not `%lld`

Comment: When you say "next to" do you mean "right at"? Because that's what it looks like. You've made `pc` point to some memory after where `a` is stored. In your case it happens to be the lower byte of `pn`. Hence when you write to the `pc` address it zeroes out part of `pn`. But that is not defined behaviour. Result may be different on different compilers, compiler options, platforms etc.

Comment: Why do you write `4 * (sizeof(char)` instead of `sizeof(int)`

Comment: You cannot cast to a character pointer and go 4 bytes beyond the initial byte of `a` in case `int` happens to be 32 bit or smaller, which is extremely likely. You are allowed to point at that address thanks to a special rule, but you are not allowed to de-reference that pointer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `char *pc = ((char *) pn ) + 4 * (sizeof(char));`, `pc` is set to point four bytes beyond where `pn` points. `pn` points to `a`, which is four bytes long (in your C implementation). Thus, we do not generally know what is at the memory that `pc` is now pointing to. The compiler is allowed to organize memory in any way it wants: After `a` in memory (probably on the stack), it may put `pn` or `pc` or data for its own use or nothing.

In `*pc = '\0';`, you put a null character (a byte with value zero) in the place pointed to by `pc`. When you write to memory using a pointer that has been manipulated to be outside the object it was taken from, the behavior is not defined by the C standard. In this case, it appears the compiler stored `pn` in memory just after `a` and that writing to `pc` in this way wrote a zero byte into `pn`.

There is no bug in the compiler here. The compiler is not obligated to provide any particular behavior when you write outside of proper addresses.

Also, note that `printf("%lld\n", (long long int) pn);` is not a proper way to print pointers. To print the pointer `pn`, use `printf("%p\n", (void *) pn);` or include `<stdint.h>` and `<inttypes.h>` and use `printf("%" PRIuPTR "\n", (uintptr_t) pn);`. With the former code, using `%p`, the output is in a form chosen by the C implementation. With the latter code, you have some control over the format; you can use `PRIuPTR` for decimal output, `PRIxPTR` for hexadecimal output, and you can add flags and other controls such as `printf("%#08" PRIxPTR "\n", (uintptr_t) pn);` to request hexadecimal format starting with "0x" and enough leading zeros so that eight digits are printed.

Answer (score 0):

<s>Looks like a bug to me. To be fair on GCC, though,</s> The code is not ideal, since we're trying to access unclaimed memory. Note that if we allocate the memory first, the issue disappears:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int a[2] = {1, 1};
    int *pn = &(a[0]);
    printf("%p\n", pn);

    char *pc = ((char *) pn ) + 4 * (sizeof(char));
    printf("%p\n", pn);

    *pc = '\0'; //This assignment changes the value of pn.
    printf("%p\n", pn);
}
```

Output on my system (64-bit):

```
$ gcc -o foo foo.c
$ ./foo

0x7ffffcfa6870
0x7ffffcfa6870
0x7ffffcfa6870
```

**Edit:** Eric [has a good point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60717003/assigning-value-to-the-location-pointed-by-one-pointer-affects-the-value-of-anot/60721441#60721441) about `pn` probably being allocated on the stack next to `a` ; so it kinda makes sense. 
Mystery solved )

Comment: It is not a bug in GCC. The program in the question writes to memory outside the object the pointer was derived from. The behavior of that is not defined by the C standard.

Comment: Bug in the posted code: yes. Bug in the compiler: no.